# I've overstayed my Schengen visa. Can I go to the UK?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, overstaying

I don't intend on coming back to the Schengen zone. I am originally from America and have been living illegally in the Schengen zone for 6 months. Could I go to the UK and try and live their legally, or would I be rejected from entering England, Ireland, the Republic of Ireland, Wales, and Scotland because of my really bad decision to overstay my Schengen thing.
God, I'm so sorry. I know this was a bad decision. My mom basically told me it was the only way for me to move to Europe, and I'm disabled and I couldn't figure anything out and she wouldn't help me.
Please help me.

Comment: You want to live in the UK? Not just go there for a short visit? Because you can't simply just do that either, you'd have to qualify for an appropriate visa. If your goal is to live and work in the UK, that's a matter for [the expatriates site](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @zach lipton I'm sorry I just don't know what I'm doing and I can't really figure this stuff out because of my autism. I would like to live in the UK, but I don't know if I'll be able to get a job. I could never get a job in the states because of my autism. :( I'm sorry I'm really distressed RN. Do you think I could enter if I got the appropriate visa? This it the OP.

Comment: You'd need to ask this question at the expatriates site for details on how you can get a visa. Unfortunately, it will likely be very difficult for an American with no particular special skills and no job offer to legally live in the UK. I'm sorry you received such bad advice to overstay. It honestly sounds like your best bet is to return to the US and to talk with an American organization that assists those with autism ( [perhaps email here now](https://www.autismspeaks.org/about-us/contact-us)). If you're stranded, the US Consulate and other organizations can help assist you in getting home.

Comment: @ZachLipton Yeah I know the advice was terrible but it was my moms, and she's still not helping me. I don't feel I can go back to the States because I'm transgender and queer as well as being disabled, and I love living in Europe because I feel so much more accepted here. I'm thinking about going to Spain, because apparently if you live illegally in Spain for two years and have a job for the last 6 months of those years, you can obtain legal residency. Here's hoping that works. :D

Comment: @user53099  true, there is a route to normalising your status, but you have it so wrong I can't even BEGIN to explain the mechanics.  See a lawyer, off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: @GayotFow fow, could I message you privately and ask you to explain?

Comment: @user53099 don't. I do not want to be contacted privately full stop. You can visit the chat room and ping me or ask the other chat room denizens.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here